# Hashing users passwords from csv import

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Need help. I've a big problem cannot resolved, i want to hash the password of all users when i import the file csv in my database. My file csv uploaded well and really work but the password never hash. My code :

**UserController.php** :

public function users_data_store() {

```
    $inputs = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($inputs, $this->file_rules);
    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    } 

    else {

        if (Input::hasFile('csv_file')) {

            $extension = Input::file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if ($extension == "csv" OR $extension == "CSV") {

                $file = Input::file('csv_file')->getRealPath();

                function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=';')
                {
                    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
                        return FALSE;

                    $header = NULL;
                    $data = array();
                    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
                    {
                        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
                        {
                            if(!$header)
                                $header = $row;
                            else
                                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                        }
                        fclose($handle);
                    }
                    /*$request->user()->fill([
                         'password' => Hash::make($request->password) // Hashing passwords
                      ])->save();*/

                    return $data;   
             }
                $areas = csv_to_array($file);
                DB::table('users')->insert($areas); 
                $path = Session::get('language');
                return Redirect::back()->with('success', Lang::get($path.'.users_import_success'));

            } else {
                return Redirect::back();
            }


        }

    }
```

}

My model - **User.php** :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User', 'guardian_id');
    }


}
```

My routes - **route.php** :

```
   Route::post('admin/user_data/store', ['as'=>'users_data_store', 'uses'=>'UserController@users_data_store']);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Past the code top of the in your file then make hash password before insert. Use the code bellow.

```
$areas = csv_to_array($file);
$areas['password'] = Hash::make($areas['password']);
DB::table('users')->insert($areas);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response brother, but it's show me  like this :  
Undefined index: password

Comment: Undefined index: password ??

Comment: user password array index name inside $areas['index or csv column name']) .

Comment: I just show you the example. You should use csv column name or password index name of $areas array.

Comment: That's mean i should to list all my table users column to reaplace  $areas??

Comment: Guide me step by step brother because this problem spend my times in 3 weeks, please,

Comment: First print_r($areas) then comment here with the array. then i can told you.

Comment: These my table coulumn :
<tr>
<th>N° matricule</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Nom complet</th>
<th>Etablissement</th>
<th>Niveau</th>
<th>Parcours</th>
<th>Sexe</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

@foreach($myusers as $myuser)
<tr>
<td>{{ $myuser->matricule }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->password }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->fullname }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->etabs }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->level }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->parcour }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->gender }}</td>
<td>{{ $myuser->type }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach

Comment: print_r($areas) then comment here with the printed of $areas array. Not db user table column.

Comment: I try print_r brother but i cannot, i don't know! really i'm already newbie, please brother,

Answer (score -1):

```
from hashlib import sha256
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

def hash_password_hack(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name) as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        with open(output_file_name,newline='',mode='w') as outfile:
            writer=csv.writer(outfile)
            hash_number=""
            hash_to_password_dict=OrderedDict()
            for password in range(0,10000):
                hash_number=sha256(b'%i'% password).hexdigest()
                hash_to_password_dict[hash_number]=password
            for row in reader:
                for hash in row[1:]:
                    writer.writerow([row[0],hash_to_password_dict[hash]])#نوشتن و ذخیره کردن
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).